# Does Aptik Save KDE Settings?

Tags: kubuntu, backup, 17.10

I'm aware that `aptik` is KDE compatible, but does it store and restore KDE settings such as desktop wallpapers, activity settings, desktop toolbar location/widgets, and virtual desktops?

Answer (score 0):

Since aptik(aptik-gtk) backs up the entire home directory excluding some temporary files and browser cache then all settings for anything should transfer provided they are stored in home.  .config, .kde etc.